# How to generate separate log files for each and every file processed using java log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jakarta-mail

I need to get a separate log file for each input file processed.
I have written an app using java,log4j,javamail api to validate the xml.it takes input ini files(to get the path of xml file to be validated).once a file is processed, it should generate the log file before going for the next file with the file name.
Finally I have to trigger an error mail for each and every ini file if it has any errors.
Present status:
Took xml path from the ini file name,validated,but its generating a single log if i process multiple file.i need separate log files for each and every log files.I will attach my entire source code with this.
Kindly help me how to achieve this using java log4j

my piece of java code:

```
static void sendmail() throws IOException,    
MessagingException,AddressException
   {
          String to1=CarParser1.to1;
          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 
HH:mm:ss");
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String to2 = CarParser1.to2;
            String to3= CarParser1.to3;
            String to4=CarParser1.to4;
            String from = CarParser1.from;
            String host = CarParser1.host;
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
            int m_toterr,m_totwarn;
            String getfilepath="";
            String pathLogFile = "D:/logfile.log";
            Enumeration enumeration = 
CarParser1.logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
            try {
                m_toterr=validatexml.Total_err;
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
InternetAddress(to1));

                message.setSubject("RE : CAR Validation Report at : 
"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); 

                 while ( enumeration.hasMoreElements() )
                 {
                       Appender appender = (Appender) 
enumeration.nextElement();
                       if ( appender instanceof FileAppender )
                       {
                          pathLogFile  = 
((FileAppender)appender).getFile(); //here you get the path
                          break;
                       }
                    }
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    FileInputStream fstream = new 
 FileInputStream(pathLogFile);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(fstream));

                    String singleLine;
                    while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    {    if(singleLine.startsWith("Error")||
 singleLine.startsWith("pls")||
 singleLine.startsWith("Total")){


                      sb.append(singleLine + "<br><br>");
                    }
                    }
                    br.close();
                    String allLines = sb.toString();
                  message.setContent(allLines, "text/html; charset=ISO-
8859-1");
                 Transport.send(message);



                System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
                CarParser1.logger.info("Email Sent Successfully...");
                System.out.println();

            } 
            catch (MessagingException mex) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Email Address.please provide 
a valid email id to send with");
                mex.printStackTrace();


            }



   }
}
```

My Log4j.properties:

```
#Log to Console as STDOUT
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss}      %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
#Log to file FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}   
%-5p %c %3x - %m%n
# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd 
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
```

please Click on the below link to download my entire project docs.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0sfw35t1obxl7s/project_docs.zip?dl=0

Thanks in Advance
Expecting Help as i have got dead-lined to submit it today.

Code for the separate Log file:

```
File dir=new File("D:/newlog");
            if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();}


            String fileName=CarParser1.si_orderid;
            File logfile=new File(dir,fileName+"_log.txt");
            if(!logfile.exists()){
            logfile.createNewFile();
            }

FileUtils.writeStringToFile(logfile,CarParser1.sb.toString());
//appending
 sb.append("\nCAR VAlidating at Path:"+final_filepath+" for the Order ID 
:"+si_orderid);
sb.append("\nUnit ID : "+si_unitid+" for the Order ID: "+si_orderid);
```

But I am getting O/P as

Java Version 1.7 or below is supported
CAR VAlidating at Path:\fms\fms_workarea\BDOPS\OPSBANK-II\SIGNALS\EFLOW\CAR\ABPEL\January-2016\Batch_16.01.16\6668662\ItemFile for the Order ID :6668662Unit ID : 2518073 for the Order ID: 6668662Order ID EqualUNIT IDEqualSupplier ID Equal

AS DUMP with no next line even though i wrote on the code.
please guide me to get the results written as read , a line by line out put as read.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Log4J works:
The log files will be written only to the file configuration mentioned in log4j.properties/.xml. Example :
***log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=D:\logfile.log***

We can configure that different level of logging like info,debug,error into different log file.

For your requirement of writing into different log files for different input files, Please do the following.
1) create a StringBuffer object and append all the information you want to log it
2) Then create a new file object with required name and dump it from Stringbuffer object.

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply.can you please guide me with a sample code .Because i am very new to this logging.

Comment: Kindly request you to guide me with a example code for the same.Thank you

Comment: Dear harisudan ,kindly have look on my update and please help me to comeover from that issue

Comment: please use sample code and customize it based on your need.                      try {
   StringBuffer logContent = new StringBuffer();
   logContent.append("file opened");
   logContent.append("message sent");
   File file = new File("filepath/custome_message_log_filename.txt");
   // if file doesnt exists, then create it
   if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
   }
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
   bw.write(logContent.toString());
   bw.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }